# Angular showing loader till component fully loads with data

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to load a css loader till the components are loaded fully.
so I just created a variable in component class and initialised it to true in `ngOnInit` liefcycle. Then I changed varibale to false on `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle.

but it keeps getting me error of `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.`

```
componentLoading: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.componentLoading = true;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.componentLoading = false;
}
```

I have saw same errors in some questions but cant understand fully on how to implement this.

The errors constructed in stackblitz
https://angular-7stwmm.stackblitz.io

Comment: Use changeDetection in ngAfterViewInit() , constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
public ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.cd.detectChanges();

}

Comment: like this?
`  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.componentLoading = false;
  }`

Comment: wrap you property inside set Timeout and try again!

Comment: It doesn't take a lot of time between `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`. It would only be an issue if you were fetching some data from a REST API and then showing it on to the view. And if that's the case, then you don't need to use `ngAfterViewInit` at all. You just need an RxJS `tap` operator to set the loading state to true and false at specific moments. What exactly is your use case anyway?

Comment: i just want to show a loader on each route hit, till the full data in the router component loads.
there are http calls also in component ngonint

Comment: @Chellappan I have tried it and its working.
but  I dont want a constant timeout for loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I give you the solution, first understand what does error **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError** means.

Normally, angular has something called **ChangeDetectionStartegy**. It is responsible for detecting any change in the property/variable values. It is through this mechanism only, that we can see the changes made in our typescript's variable reflected on our Html page. You can read in-depth about it [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/).

Now, during the development, this process is run twice for every change (only once in production mode). One for detecting the change and second for verifying the change. It happens in millisecond/nanosecond. During these 2 steps, if the variable/property changes its value, then angular will throw this warning. **This is what is happening in your case.** There are multiple ways to overcome this:

1. **Using setTimeout**(easier but not recommended).

```js
    ngAfterViewInit() {
     setTimeout(() => {
     this.componentLoading = false;
    });
    }
```

2. using custom logic:

   a. Start the loader from the previous component.
   b. Stop the loader in the constructor of the current component.
                     or
   if your component needs the data from service, then stop it after observables success/error event.

Comment: what if i have multiple http calls in ngonint which are not chained?
where can i add loader stoping code?
also what u meant by starting loader from prevoious loader? is it possible to use ngDestroy?

Comment: If you have multiple Http calls which are not chained, then I assume they are independent of each other. In this case, I would suggest stopping the loader on that Http call which has the data that user need to see the first or most important to the user. For the second part, i mean start loader on ngDestroy of previous component (if you are coming to this component by navigation and not directly landing the user on this component).